# Filter values from a dataframe using group_by or filter?

Tags: r, filter, group-by, dplyr

Hi I have the following example,
`df`

```
#First Name Second Name Subject Score
#Harry  Kane    Biology 0
#Harry  Kane    Physics 25
#Harry  Kane    Math    19
#Harry  Kane    Social  16
#Harry  Kane    History 19

#Tom    Hault   Biology 0
#Tom    Hault   Physics 22
#Tom    Hault   Math    24
#Tom    Hault   Social  25
#Tom    Hault   History 20

#Ben    Capario Biology 0
#Ben    Capario Physics 12
#Ben    Capario Math    15
#Ben    Capario Social  16
#Ben    Capario History 18

#Phil   Adams   Biology 20
#Phil   Adams   Physics 22
#Phil   Adams   Math    17
#Phil   Adams   Social  15
#Phil   Adams   History 18

#Shawn  Salzensky   Biology 25
#Shawn  Salzensky   Physics 22
#Shawn  Salzensky   Math    18
#Shawn  Salzensky   Social  19
#Shawn  Salzensky   History 12
```

Each individual has their names and their scores in individual subjects.

I am trying for an output in this format,

```
df1

#First Name Second Name Subject Score
#Harry  Kane    Biology 0
#Harry  Kane    Physics 25
#Tom    Hault   Biology 0
#Tom    Hault   Physics 22
#Ben    Capario Biology 0
#Ben    Capario Physics 12
```

I had tried this:

```
 df1 <- filter(df, {Subject=='Biology'&`Score`== 0} | {Subject=='Physics'&`Score`!= 0})
```

However, it takes 'subject' and 'score' individually returning elements which consist Biology and their respective score, and also score which is == 0.

Any other way possible?

Comment: Could you provide useful sample data ?

Comment: `filter` keeps certain rows. You could try converting from long to wide here so it's one row per person.

Comment: save them as a `data.frame` and then use `table`. Could you upload your data as  `data.frame` format, that would be easy to replicate your example?

Comment: I've reread your question and realized I have no idea what you're looking for. If you want something that looks like the codeblock in the bit under "I am trying for an output in this format", it's below. It's entirely unclear what you got with your "I have tried this" code block, though.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the code. It worked and is giving me the desired output.

Comment: @SriharshaP I'm glad it worked! If it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is all the cases (rows) where there is a `Biology` `Score` of `0` and all the cases (rows) where there is a `Physics` `Score` that is not `0`, the form of your code works. Formatting suggestions, though: use `()` to enclose logical expressions. In a dplyr call, don't quote variable names unless they have a space in them. Don't alternate quotes and back tics.

```
df1 <- filter(df, (Subject == 'Biology' & Score == 0) | (Subject == 'Physics' & Score != 0))
df1
#   First.Name Second.Name Subject Score
# 1      Harry        Kane Biology     0
# 2      Harry        Kane Physics    25
# 3        Tom       Hault Biology     0
# 4        Tom       Hault Physics    22
# 5        Ben     Capario Biology     0
# 6        Ben     Capario Physics    12
# 7       Phil       Adams Physics    22
# 8      Shawn   Salzensky Physics    22
```

I'd add that the data may look weird, but it is tidy. Each row is an observation of a score. This is the way you want your data, even if it doesn't look like a gradebook.

#### Data:

```
df <- data.frame("First Name" = rep(c("Harry", "Tom", "Ben", "Phil", "Shawn"), each = 5),
                 "Second Name" = rep(c("Kane", "Hault", "Capario", "Adams", "Salzensky"), each = 5),
                 Subject = rep(c("Biology", "Physics", "Math", "Social", "History"), times = 5),
                 Score = c(0, 25, 19, 16, 19, 0, 22, 24, 25, 20, 0, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 22, 17, 15, 18, 25, 22, 18, 19, 12),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
   First.Name Second.Name Subject Score
1       Harry        Kane Biology     0
2       Harry        Kane Physics    25
3       Harry        Kane    Math    19
4       Harry        Kane  Social    16
5       Harry        Kane History    19
6         Tom       Hault Biology     0
7         Tom       Hault Physics    22
8         Tom       Hault    Math    24
9         Tom       Hault  Social    25
10        Tom       Hault History    20
11        Ben     Capario Biology     0
12        Ben     Capario Physics    12
13        Ben     Capario    Math    15
14        Ben     Capario  Social    16
15        Ben     Capario History    18
16       Phil       Adams Biology    20
17       Phil       Adams Physics    22
18       Phil       Adams    Math    17
19       Phil       Adams  Social    15
20       Phil       Adams History    18
21      Shawn   Salzensky Biology    25
22      Shawn   Salzensky Physics    22
23      Shawn   Salzensky    Math    18
24      Shawn   Salzensky  Social    19
25      Shawn   Salzensky History    12
```